# query from nhibernate Criteria api to linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I want to translate following query from nhibernate criteria query api to linq.

```
 var userquery = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User))
          .SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize)
          .SetMaxResults(pageSize);

 var totalcountQuery = CriteriaTransformer.Clone(userquery)
           .SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64());
```

Thanks

Update

```
IEnumerable<User> dbUsers = userquery.Future<User>();
IFutureValue<long> count = totalcountQuery.FutureValue<long>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct(ish) translation would be:

```
var userQuery = session.Query<User>().Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

var totalCount = userQuery.LongCount();
```

However I'm not sure why you'd want to do the count after the Skip & Take, I would think something like:

```
var totalCount = session.Query<User>().LongCount();
```

would be closer to what you want

See http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Executing-future-queries-with-NHibernate-Linq.aspx

For futures on Linq, you could do:

```
var users = userQuery.ToFuture();    
var totalCount = userQuery.LongCount(); // users will be a future, count won't be but if it's only 2 queries then this will execute them both
```

Comment: I needed in implementing custom membership provider, thanks though

Comment: Question is updated, can you translate this added two lines in linq, thanks